# how to call a function with a decorator by clicking a button in a telethone?

Tags: telegram

```
@client.on(events.New Message("channel_name"))
async def parse(event):
   await client.forward_messages(id, event.message)
```

How to start this method by clicking the button in the telegram bot?

I tried to do something like this

```
async def send_one(callback: CallbackQuery):
    async with TelegramClient(client) as cl:

        @cl.on(events.NewMessage("channel_name"))
        async def handler(event):
            await cl.forward_messages(id, event.message)
```